# How to Check Context Menu Dropdown Items, VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

MY application has a context menu that appears when the user right-clicks a form. The context menu is generated on each click since the items depend on various application variables.

Each context menu contains a number of items and several DropDown sub-menus.

As the context menu is created, I can set items on the primary menu as checked as follows:

```
MenuItemX.Checked = True
```

However, I cannot find a way to make items in the Dropdown menu checked. I can create these items OK, but the line of code above does not allow me to set them as checked.

Is it possible to have items within a Dropdown sub-menu checked, and to set this property at run-time?

Can anyone provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: I don't know if you can "Check" DropDown menu item... You can certainly "Select" them, not sure about check.

Comment: After much testing, seems not. Problem with .Select() is that it's not permanent. Looking for a way to mark one of the Dropdown items as an option that is currently selected. Thought about changing the font in some way (bold, perhaps), but seems all the font attributes for this type of item are read-only.

Comment: I am doing some tests trying to replicate the scenario, but my ComboBox options are always selected even after I close and reopen the menu... Do you create new instances of the menu with every click?

Comment: Yes, I create a new instance every time the user right-clicks. Each time, I can use .Select() to make one of the Dropdown items appear selected, but if, e.g., the user moves elsewhere in the menu with the mouse cursor a different item is selected. As above, I really need to have an item in the Dropdown menu permanently marked as different to the others.

Comment: I found a solution for me. Rather than adding a series of ToolStripMenuItem items to the Dropdown menu, add ToolStripButton items. These can be checked even when part of a Dropdown menu (although they don't actually appear checked, just permanently selected).

Comment: You can simulate this by changing the image property to an appropriate 'checked' image or Nothing.
'sender.Image = If(sender.Image Is Nothing, imlIcons.Images("Check"), Nothing).'